# Notepad++ regex removing string with static and variable data

Tags: regex, notepad++

I think I have solved this, but I'm wondering if anyone sees a flaw or a better method:

Using a regular expression in Notebook++ I'm trying to remove all strings that contain static and variable info like this:

`{start of line},1,NRAG-E21-PRDCT-DT-CRWLR-8416 Result Data,NRAG-E21-PRDCT-DT-CRWLR-8416 Result Data,1,http:<l></l>//www.url.com/product/10E026,`

-note: both `,1,` strings are variable as well `,1, ,2, ,3,` etc...

The advantage that I have is that it appears at the end of the string - just before the comma - the pattern is always `[0-9] [A-Z] [0-9]`

it, therefore, seems that this should work:

```
^.*?\/[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+,
```

That selects the start of the line `^` followed by everything before the pattern that looks like `/10E026` and the comma at the end.

Does anybody see a flaw or a better way to find a string like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That selects the start of the line ^ followed by everything before the pattern that looks like /10E026 and the comma at the end.

That is not so. your `^.*?\/[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+,` matches the start of a line (`^`), any 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible up to the first `/`, then a `/`, 1+ digits, 1+ uppercase ASCII letters, 1+ digits, and a comma - anywhere inside the string

It seems you need  to match up to the last occurrence of the `/xxAAAxxx,` pattern:

```
^.*/[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+,
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM9bR6/4)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of a line (in Notepad++, `^` matches line start by default)
- `.*` - 0+ any chars but a newline, greedily, up to the last...
- `/` - forward slash (no need escaping here)
- `[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+` - 1+ digits, 1+ uppercase letters, 1+ digits
- `,` - a comma.

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly, although I neglected an important piece of info. My string example does not end with the end of the line. There can be 4,000 characters in one line after that example string. I think we can just take out the $ at the end of the expression as in this example:  https://regex101.com/r/mM9bR6/3

Comment: Please check the answer now.